# iOS Simulator always ask for logging in to the Apple account upon launch

Tags: ios, xcode

Whenever I build and run my iOS app on Xcode 12 the Simulator always asks me to log in to an Apple ID account upon launch. This is not true until Xcode 10 but recently I started using Xcode again and the simulator always shows the login dialog.

However, I already logged in to the Apple account from General app on the Simulator, and the login was successful (it shows my name on the screen). But still, whenever I launch the app the login dialog shows.

Is this possibly a bug? How can I remove it? I use Xcode 12.3.

Comment: By "General app" do you mean the Settings app? And by "login dialog" do you mean a popup inside your app?

Comment: @PDK Both are correct.

Comment: To diagnose the problem, you need to update your question with the code that triggers the login dialog in your app — and handles the login.